# Gallery Intent is not working on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-gallery

This is My Code for Fetching the image from Gallery

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
```

and this is `onActivityResult()` method

```
if(requestCode==2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){

            Uri _uri = data.getData();
            if (_uri != null) {

            //User had pick an image.
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            //Link to the image
            final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ConfirmPicture.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED, true);
            intent.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", imageFilePath);
            intent.putExtra("OUTLET_ID", 0);
            intent.putExtra("OUTLET_NAME", "name");
            startActivity(intent);
           }
```

This Code is working fine on android 2.3.4 version but when I tested this code on a 4.0.3 device, it's not working, what could be the problem?

Comment: when you say: "it's not working" what exactly do you mean? Can you be more specific about what it does and doesn't do? i.e. is there an exception thrown? or does it simply not open up the gallery? Is there any message in the Logcat at the time that you try to fire off the intent?

Comment: the imageFilePath in the method  provides me the right path to the image via gallery intent but its not showing in the ImageView. in 4.0.3 version.

Comment: have you got the ans of it if yes then pls share i am also having the same problem

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
       ZootOutObject.objectUri = getImagePath();
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, ZootOutObject.objectUri);
       startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_INTENT);

Answer (score 0):

I had Solved this issue

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            ZootOutObject.objectUri = getImagePath();
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, ZootOutObject.objectUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_INTENT);
```

if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

```
             String pathName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder_name/image_zootout.jpg";

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PhotoEditorActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", pathName);
             intent.putExtra("OUTLET_ID", 0);
             intent.putExtra("OUTLET_NAME", "");
             startActivity(intent);

       }


private Uri getImagePath() {
    // If sd card is available
        if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .getAbsolutePath();
            filename = "image_zootout.jpg";
            path += "/folder_name";
            File file = new File(path);
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            path += "/" + filename;
            File imageFile = new File(path);
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    imageFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        }else{ // If sd card is not available
            return null;
        }
    }
```